# Algorithm to find in a group of button if the clicked button is the first button

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm

I am trying to get to a good algorithm for the following use case:

**1. I have a group of on off button say 5**

**2. I can multiselect those buttons (selected first then second --- )**

**3. I want to know out of the button selected which on is the first.**

so basically i want to do something on the first (and only) selected button.

any help?

I am thinking of a approach : 
take a global variable x=0, and when a button is set to on increment that variable and when a button is set to off decrease by one.. and when the variable change from 0 to 1 means the button clicked is the only button which is on.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really understand but I'm trying :

Each button has a different value.

You save each click into an array and the first value is the first clicked button.